# Debugger out of sync when debugging OS source code

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, camera

I am attempting to find out what is causing a runtime exception "setParameters failed" with my camera. So I ran my program in the (eclipse) debugger (which normally works perfectly) and stepped into the OS's (or more specifically the Camera class) setParameters method. Unfortunately it appears as if the correspondence between the code that is shown in the debug view is out of sync with the code being executed. For example at one point the cursor appears at the start of a multi line comment and then when I repeatedly clicked the "step over" button, the cursor advanced several times than jumped back four or five lines and started advancing again as if it was executing a small loop. But this was all going on within the bounds of a comment! On further inspection, I did see a "for" loop not too far above the cursor that perhaps was being executed.

Is this a glitch that could possibly be corrected?

**EDIT:** If I could modify the Camera class source code so I could add in some log messages, then that would be an alternative debugging route, but can that be done?